# Dual Boot a light-weight variant of Ubuntu on a Toshiba Satellite L505

Tags: toshiba-satellite

So I have Windows installed on a Toshiba L505, I'm perfectly fine with Windows but my battery life is extremely low.

Right now, I'm not planning on getting a new battery but I am wondering if I can use some very light weight variant of Ubuntu so I can connect to the internet on-the-go and use Windows at home. I would also need the distro to be uninstallable (which I don't know how to do...)

Last time I tried Ubuntu on a Toshiba, the fan went crazy and it used to crash continuously, I don't want to risk that with this Toshiba.

All help is much appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to install Xubuntu using [WUBI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide).

I would suggest getting [Xubuntu 12.04, Precise Pangolin](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/). You should be able to just mount the iso file using [daemon tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/products/dtLite) and install it like any other windows app. You can trivially uninstall it as well using `Add and Remove Programs`.

Ultimately if your battery is failing, I dont know how much a light weight distro will help. You could go lighter than Xubuntu though, but I would suggest you start with it.

Comment: thanks, I know wubi is the "installer" version, are there any downsides to it versus just installing it? Sorry, Linux noob here :) I've also heard of Lubuntu, what are your views on it?

Comment: @fermionoid I have used Wubi happily for quite a long time, and have no major issues with it, I have recently transitioned to full install, so am not sure of its latest state. Primary thing is that power cuts/ unsafe shutdowns affect Wubi installs. Lubuntu is what I meant by "lighter", however I believe Xubuntu is older, and at any case works very well on a netbook of mine, so I am a Xubuntu fan :)

Comment: Ultimately for your use case of a backup OS that can be easily removed, I believe WUBI is your best option. At worst you can undo it easiy :)

Comment: Ok, I'll give your method a shot and I'll get back to you! Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering, I have a 200gb hdd, how many gb shall I give to Linux?

Comment: @fermionoid depends on your usage, 5-10 should be plenty for a basic use. you can go with 15-20 for a more future proof install if you can spare it. There are (were, atleast) unofficial ways to resize it later or even to move it to a full install, just fyi.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It doesn't really work with Toshiba as I've come to realize but I've marked it anyways as it makes sense and is going on the right lines.